# Does framer animation works with position "fixed"?

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

//this is my component

```
import React from 'react'
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import style from './header.module.css';

function Header() {
    return (
        <motion.div
            className={style.Header}
            initial={{ opacity:0,position:"fixed"}}
            animate={{  opacity:1}}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{
                duration: 3,
            }}
        >
            <ul className={style.headerul}>
                <li className={style.headerli}>HOME</li>
                <li className={style.headerli}>MENU</li>
                <li className={style.headerli}>ABOUT US</li>
                <li className={style.headerli}>CONTACT US</li>
            </ul>
        </motion.div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Suggest if there is any alter native to do animation on this element,Thank You in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are merely animating `opacity` and not transforming its position, you can simply omit the `position` in the `initial` prop and place it in your CSS file instead. It will still work the same way but if there are any other animations or styles which you haven't mentioned in your code, you should consider editing your question to disclose such details.

Although, to answer the question in the simplest way possible -- yes, framer motion animations do work with `fixed` positioning.

In any case, do let me know whether or not the suggestions worked. Good luck!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb is, the initial prop is use to define how particular elements are supposed to look when the component they're a part of is mounted/fires up. Animate is used for defining how elements of the said component must look once the animation is completed. Therefore, if you are not animating some property, there shouldn't be a reason to mention a value to that property in the animation configurations.